# Kendo Chart control won't render correct SVG in IE 10

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, donut-chart

I am testing out creating a SPA using the Kendo UI Pro suite. I have an issue currently with the Kendo UI Chart (in Donut mode). The chart's SVG does not properly render in IE 10. This issue does not appear to happen in IE 11 or Firefox.

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m9vq7gu4/

In the View's Show event, I call to an ajax API and get the data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            "TotalHours": Math.random() * 714,
                "Budget": 714.6
        }),
        delay: 2
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var data = [{
            value: response.TotalHours,
            color: "red"
        }, {
            value: response.Budget - response.TotalHours,
            color: "transparent"
        }];
        loadRadial(id, data);
    }
});
```

I then kendoChart the div and refresh it.

```
var dsRadial = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data
});
dsRadial.read();
var radial = $("#" + id).kendoChart({
    dataSource: dsRadial,
    dataBound: function () {
        console.log("dataBound");
    },
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "donut",
        holeSize: 60,
        size: 20
    },
    series: [{
        field: "value",
        colorField: "color"
    }],
    chartArea: {
        background: "transparent"
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true
    }
}).data("kendoChart");
```

I show that all events down the View/Layout/Router fire correctly. At first I thought that the chart was not binding properly, but if I look at the source code of the page the SVG is created:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="left: 0px; top: -0.47px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1"><defs><radialGradient id="5c7e3a1b-06a7-4665-bb46-44db26b308e7" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cx="409.5" cy="100" r="80"><stop style="stop-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); stop-opacity: 0;" offset="0.75" /><stop style="stop-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); stop-opacity: 0.3;" offset="0.875" /><stop style="stop-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); stop-opacity: 0;" offset="0.9975" /></radialGradient></defs><g><path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0 0 L 819 0 L 819 200 L 0 200 Z" /><path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 5 5 L 814 5 L 814 195 L 5 195 Z" /><g><g /></g><g><g><g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"><path fill="red" stroke="none" d="M 409.5 20 C 428.398 20 447.219 26.963 461.567 39.263 C 475.915 51.563 485.673 69.099 488.56 87.775 C 491.448 106.452 487.443 126.115 477.48 142.174 C 467.517 158.233 451.679 170.556 433.663 176.264 L 427.622 157.198 C 441.134 152.917 453.013 143.675 460.485 131.631 C 467.957 119.587 470.961 104.839 468.795 90.831 C 466.629 76.824 459.311 63.672 448.55 54.447 C 437.789 45.222 423.674 40 409.5 40 Z" /><path fill="url(#5c7e3a1b-06a7-4665-bb46-44db26b308e7)" stroke="none" d="M 409.5 20 C 428.398 20 447.219 26.963 461.567 39.263 C 475.915 51.563 485.673 69.099 488.56 87.775 C 491.448 106.452 487.443 126.115 477.48 142.174 C 467.517 158.233 451.679 170.556 433.663 176.264 L 427.622 157.198 C 441.134 152.917 453.013 143.675 460.485 131.631 C 467.957 119.587 470.961 104.839 468.795 90.831 C 466.629 76.824 459.311 63.672 448.55 54.447 C 437.789 45.222 423.674 40 409.5 40 Z" /></g><g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"><path fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 433.663 176.264 C 416.13 181.819 396.674 181.079 379.614 174.208 C 362.554 167.337 348.016 154.387 339.227 138.231 C 330.437 122.076 327.462 102.835 330.961 84.779 C 334.461 66.723 344.408 49.987 358.597 38.284 C 372.785 26.582 391.108 20 409.5 20 L 409.5 40 C 395.706 40 381.964 44.936 371.322 53.713 C 360.681 62.49 353.22 75.043 350.596 88.584 C 347.972 102.126 350.203 116.557 356.795 128.674 C 363.387 140.79 374.291 150.503 387.086 155.656 C 399.881 160.809 414.473 161.364 427.622 157.198 Z" /><path fill="url(#5c7e3a1b-06a7-4665-bb46-44db26b308e7)" stroke="none" d="M 433.663 176.264 C 416.13 181.819 396.674 181.079 379.614 174.208 C 362.554 167.337 348.016 154.387 339.227 138.231 C 330.437 122.076 327.462 102.835 330.961 84.779 C 334.461 66.723 344.408 49.987 358.597 38.284 C 372.785 26.582 391.108 20 409.5 20 L 409.5 40 C 395.706 40 381.964 44.936 371.322 53.713 C 360.681 62.49 353.22 75.043 350.596 88.584 C 347.972 102.126 350.203 116.557 356.795 128.674 C 363.387 140.79 374.291 150.503 387.086 155.656 C 399.881 160.809 414.473 161.364 427.622 157.198 Z" /></g></g></g></g></svg>
```

What's really odd is that as soon as I switch the router over to the other page, the SVG displays properly until the data is changed again (you can see this by clicking the Home/Data links on the demo). What could be causing this other than a weird issue between Chart and View/Layout/Router?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Kendo UI prior to versions 2013.2.1215 (an internal build).

It's caused by a glitch in the IE10 SVG implementation. Once a path is scaled to 0 it disappears even if the transformation is cleared.